# How do I write a function to autodownload pdf files from a link without navigating to another webpage either in java script or html

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement the auto download feature in my web application where when clicked on a button a pdf file should download. I have the link but I am not able to download the file . I have used http get also and ionic file transfer plugin but neither of them are working. Can anyone help me write a code that does this task?

Comment: You just need to point the 'autodownload' button to your PDF direct link.

Comment: How? @darklightcode

Comment: `<a href='LINK_TO_PDF' >AUTODOWNLOAD</a>` , that's all ( as long as the PDF is marked as an attachment upon opening it ).

Comment: i have tried that. It navigated to that webpage and displayed the pdf

Comment: i even tried data-auto-download attribute it redirects me to another webpage

Comment: If you tried something already, you should add the existing code to your question

Comment: Do you know of any other way we can work it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new download attribute for  elements (new in HTML5). The following is from "https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp"

"Specify a value for the download attribute, which will be the new filename of the downloaded file ("myFile.pdf" instead of "sampleFile.pdf"):"

```
<a href="/files/sampleFile.pdf" download="myFile.pdf">Download PDF</a>
```

```html
<a href="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf" download="myFile.pdf">Download PDF</a>
```

Comment: <a href="https://www.cin.ufpe.br/~tfl2/artificial-intelligence-modern-approach.9780131038059.25368.pdf" download = "artificial-intelligence-modern-approach.9780131038059.25368.pdf" > download </a>

Comment: this is what im using. it doesnt download the pdf it navigates to that link

Comment: yeah i just tried it in a normal webpage  as well - in Chrome. Same result as you got - maybe ists a browser safety thing? - on a positive note - I was able to download the pdf via right click and "save as...". You might need to have a "right click to save as ... instructuion on your link

Comment: no in the webapp im using ive to autodownload the pdf. I guess it might be a safety thing. thanks anyway :)